# Why there is no python pip3.7?

Tags: pip

My python version is 3.70. *sudo python3 --version*.
I installed pip3 using below command:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

But while I checked pip3 version by: `pip3 --version`

**pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python
3.4)**

Why it is not installing for python3.7?

Comment: because your apt source provide `python3.4` version. upgrade pip version you can try `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Can you also share the result of `which python3` command?

Comment: @pwxcoo i tried your comment, but i got result as  `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip` . Also i tried `python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3`, i got result as `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip3`
"

Answer (score 17):

try the commands mentioned below:

1. apt install -y python3-pip.
2. python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: What @rajesh said

Comment: well, there is no mention of "apt install -y python3-pip".

Answer (score 1):

if you have your python3.7 already installed, you can set an alias for pip within .bashrc, so that you can simply use `pip install ...` and be sure that it will install to 3.7

in terminal write
`gedit /home/$your_user_name$/.bashrc`

then add somwhere in the top
`alias pip3.7='python3.7 -m pip'`
or `alias pip='python -m pip'`